# Unable to open the google docs from google drive by using google client API in android application

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

When I fetch the google doc from google drive in my android application Since I am getting "File is not openable" message error.

from **DriveApi.DriveContentsResult** and `DriveApi.DriveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()` have to be false.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using [`DriveContents`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveContents) since **`DriveApi.DriveContentsResult`** interface was deprecated. Also, check the permission that you have set.

Comment: I am using com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.4.0 for google drive. In which DriveContents is  not available.Please provide me appropriate solution to resolved  this issue.

Comment: What is the interface to replace the ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>?